# OCR in Sage Maker

Tags: amazon-web-services, ocr, amazon-sagemaker, text-classification

Guys i am trying to build infrastructure on aws for getting help from others on annotation. currently we uses label-studio for text annotation. as might know you can label text by selecting through polygon and than writing what does selected area mean. ex: if polygon is made around english word than what writing out label  of it to annotate that given english word. for more see image below.[image]

How can i do this in **SageMaker Ground Truth**. as far as i have gone i think it can just label pre defined words. you cant create custom label in it by selecting any given area using polygon in image am i right ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately LS doesn't support changing of labels on the fly.